# How to add two columns with specified condition in SAS?

Tags: sas

How to add  two columns with specified condition in SAS?

Here I want to add the column data that is specified in first 2 columns.

```
    data data1;
      set data;
      column1 = x;
      column2 = y;
      total = column1 + column2;
    run;

    input
    x   y   a   b   c   d   e
    --  --  --  --  --  --  --
    a   c   1   45  32  7   45
    b   a   22  45  55  33  55
    d   e   56  78  66  44  12
    c   d   33  45  44  56  77

    Output
    x   y   a   b   c   d   e   Output
    --  --  --  --  --  --  --  ------
    a   c   1   45  32  7   45  33
    b   a   22  45  55  33  55  67
    d   e   56  78  66  44  12  56
    c   d   33  45  44  56  77  100
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I'm sure there's a cleaner way of doing this, but this works:

```
data data;
   input
    x $ y $ a   b   c   d   e;
   datalines;
    a   c   1   45  32  7   45
    b   a   22  45  55  33  55
    d   e   56  78  66  44  12
    c   d   33  45  44  56  77
    ;
run;

data data1;
    set data;
    count = _n_;
run;

proc sql noprint;
    select count into: countlist
    separated by " " from data1;
quit;

proc sql noprint;
    select x into: xlist
    separated by " " from data1;
quit;

proc sql noprint;
    select y into: ylist
    separated by " " from data1;
quit;

%macro add;

    data data2 (drop = count);
        set data1;
        %do i = 1 %to %sysfunc(countw(&countlist.));
        %let this_x = %scan(&xlist., &i.);
        %let this_y = %scan(&ylist., &i.);
            if &i. = count then total = &this_x. + &this_y.;
        %end;
    run;

%mend add;

%add;
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simpler solution.  Create an array of the possible numbers to add, loop through them and check if the variable name is the same as the value in `x` or `y`, using the `vname` function.

```
data have;
input x $ y $  a   b   c   d   e;
datalines;
a   c   1   45  32  7   45
b   a   22  45  55  33  55
d   e   56  78  66  44  12
c   d   33  45  44  56  77
;
run;

data want;
set have;
array vars{*} a--e;
output=0;
do i = 1 to dim(vars);
    if x=vname(vars{i}) then output+vars{i};
    if y=vname(vars{i}) then output+vars{i};
end;
drop i;
run;
```

Comment: @Joe I'm not sure I follow.  `output` is reset to 0 at the start of every row